# How to write a more efficient mysql:select the record containg max date when to group by code?

Tags: mysql

Show create table structure with;

```
CREATE TABLE `quote` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17449887 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Every code group has different max(date),select code and its max(date) with:

```
select code,max(date) as date from quote group by code;
```

I want to get records grouped by code and date is max(date) in its code group and other columns' value.

```
create table b SELECT code,max(date) as date from quote group by code ;
select * from quote as a , b where a.code = b.code and a.date = b.date;
```

The efficient is extremly low,how to write a new efficient mysql code ?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? *The efficient is extremly low* Do not create a table, use subquery. And add proper index.

Comment: `Show columns` is not useful, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output.

Comment: We generally find SHOW CREATE TABLE more useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be sort of asking multiple things here.  To speed up this query:

```sql
SELECT code, MAX(date) AS date FROM quote GROUP BY code;
```

you want this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON quote (code, date);
```

I suspect that the second query you have in mind is trying to find the records for each code having the maximum date.  That query might look something like:

```
SELECT q1.*
FROM quote q1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT code, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM quote
    GROUP BY code
) q2
    ON q2.code = q1.code AND
       q2.max_date = q1.date;
```

The same index suggested above should also help this version of the query.

Comment: and change `code` to a varchar of an appropriate length first.